# ViewPager detect when user is trying to swipe out of bounds

Tags: android

I am using the ViewPager consisting of 6 pages to display some data. I want to be able to call a method when the user is at position 0 and tries to swipe to the right (backwards), or at position 5 and tries to swipe to the left (forward), even though no more pages exist for these directions. Is there any way I can listen for these scenarios?

Comment: Hi all, I have used the code but the onSwipeOutLister method is not called in my activity even if I call the method. please see my question posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25889115/android-viewpager-detect-swipe-beyond-the-bounds

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Extend ViewPager and override `onInterceptTouchEvent()` like this:

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

    float mStartDragX;
    OnSwipeOutListener mListener;


    public void setOnSwipeOutListener(OnSwipeOutListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        float x = ev.getX();
        switch (ev.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mStartDragX = x;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (mStartDragX < x && getCurrentItem() == 0) {
                mListener.onSwipeOutAtStart();
            } else if (mStartDragX > x && getCurrentItem() == getAdapter().getCount() - 1) {
                mListener.onSwipeOutAtEnd();
            }
            break;
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    public interface OnSwipeOutListener {
        public void onSwipeOutAtStart();
        public void onSwipeOutAtEnd();
    }

}
```

Comment: I have created a class called CustomViewPager and implemented the method above. How do I communicate back with my activity when one of the If statement conditions are met? Is there some sort of way of setting up a listener or something in my activity using the ViewPager object?

Comment: I updated my answer. You just need to call `setOnSwipeOutListener()` in your activity. I didn't run this code, so it may need to make a few ajustments.

Comment: Hi all, I have used the code but the onSwipeOutLister method is not called in my activity even if I call the method. please see my question posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25889115/android-viewpager-detect-swipe-beyond-the-bounds

Comment: For me onInterceptTouchEvent not generating continuous MOVE event. Any suggestion here http://stackoverflow.com/q/28605921/2624806.

Comment: @M.A.Murali Check my answer to see how to hook up your activity to this `CustomViewPager` - http://stackoverflow.com/a/31275349/1617737

Comment: @FlávioFaria its gettting called twice

Answer (score 18):

Thanks a lot to @Flavio, although i had to do some changes to his code because the callbacks methods were firing twice, also I added code to check if there was any registered listener, to avoid app crashing when there is no listener registered. This is the code I used to make it work, with both onSwipeOutAtStart and onSwipeOutAtEnd:

```
public class CustomViewPager extends android.support.v4.view.ViewPager {

    float mStartDragX;
    OnSwipeOutListener mOnSwipeOutListener;

    public CustomViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void setOnSwipeOutListener(OnSwipeOutListener listener) {
        mOnSwipeOutListener = listener;
    }

    private void onSwipeOutAtStart() {
        if (mOnSwipeOutListener!=null) {
            mOnSwipeOutListener.onSwipeOutAtStart();
        }
    }

    private void onSwipeOutAtEnd() {
        if (mOnSwipeOutListener!=null) {
            mOnSwipeOutListener.onSwipeOutAtEnd();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        switch(ev.getAction() & MotionEventCompat.ACTION_MASK){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mStartDragX = ev.getX();
                break;
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){

        if(getCurrentItem()==0 || getCurrentItem()==getAdapter().getCount()-1){
            final int action = ev.getAction();
            float x = ev.getX();
            switch(action & MotionEventCompat.ACTION_MASK){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if (getCurrentItem()==0 && x>mStartDragX) {
                        onSwipeOutAtStart();
                    }
                    if (getCurrentItem()==getAdapter().getCount()-1 && x<mStartDragX){
                        onSwipeOutAtEnd();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }else{
            mStartDragX=0;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);

    }

    public interface OnSwipeOutListener {
        void onSwipeOutAtStart();
        void onSwipeOutAtEnd();
    }
}
```

Comment: Works a treat (with only one callback for each swipe!). BTW, you may want to make your activity `implements CustomViewPager.OnSwipeOutListener` and, also in your activity, don't forget to call `myCustomViewPager.setOnSwipeOutListener(this);` on your CustomViewPager object.

Comment: The best solution! Thank you!

Comment: It is not work, setCurrentItem performed but not swipe, on MotionEvent.ACTION_UP it is not work but on MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE swipe but not correctly. On activity I use setCurrentItem with thread and worked, I will add answer.

Comment: Dear @Kanan, did you make your activity implement CustomViewPager.OnSwipeOutListener and in your activity, do you call myCustomViewPager.setOnSwipeOutListener(this); on your CustomViewPager object?

Comment: @spacebiker yes

Answer (score 17):

The answer from Flávio Faria doesn't work for me. The only event I get in onInterceptTouchEvent() is ACTION_DOWN event. So I override the onTouchEvent() method to get it work.

Here is the code. Note that I only have onSwipeOutAtEnd() in the listener. You can add your code to support swiping left on first vier.

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

float mStartDragX;
OnSwipeOutListener mListener;


public void setOnSwipeOutListener(OnSwipeOutListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
    if(getCurrentItem()==getAdapter().getCount()-1){
        final int action = ev.getAction();
        float x = ev.getX();
        switch(action & MotionEventCompat.ACTION_MASK){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mStartDragX = x;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if (x<mStartDragX){
                mListener.onSwipeOutAtEnd();
            }else{
                mStartDragX = 0;
            }
            break;
        }
    }else{
        mStartDragX=0;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}    
public interface OnSwipeOutListener {
    public void onSwipeOutAtEnd();
}
```

Comment: You'll be receiving only `ACTION_DOWN` in `onInterceptTouchEvent()` if you return `true` from that method.

Comment: Hi all, I have used the code but the onSwipeOutLister method is not called in my activity even if I call the method. please see my question posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25889115/android-viewpager-detect-swipe-beyond-the-bounds

Comment: I actually found out that receiving `move` depends on the contents of the pager. I used to add `LinearLayout` and I was not receiving the move. When I wrapped the layout in `ScrollView` then it started working - a bit more complex layout, though.

Comment: You saved my day my friend ! Thank you !

Answer (score 16):

How about setting an [OnPageChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOnPageChangeListener(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener)) on your ViewPager? Then you can modify your navigation arrows or whatever in the onPageScrolled.

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            updateNavigationArrows();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }
});
```

Comment: The method `setOnPageChangeListener()` is deprecated in newer SDKs and was replaced with `addOnPageChangeListener()`.

Answer (score 4):

I wonder how it worked for others, it's not working for me.

`onInterceptTouchEvent()` only takes `ACTION_DOWN` event. While `onTouchEvent()` only takes one event at a time either `ACTION_DOWN`, `ACTION_UP` and others.

I had to override both `onInterceptTouchEvent()` and `onTouchEvent()` to make it work properly. The `ACTION_DOWN` of `onInterceptTouchEvent` grabs initial `X` point of touch, and `OnTouchEvent` grabs final `X2` point. Which I compared it to detect swipe direction.

Get initial X value of the touch:

```
float x1 = 0;
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        switch(ev.getAction() & MotionEventCompat.ACTION_MASK){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            x1 = ev.getX();
            break;
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }
```

From tjlian616's code, the `onTouchEvent()` listens to `ACTION_UP` and gets it's last `X` Value.
While I've set my current item's value to be 0 to get swipe out at start listener. Compared it and add fired up the listener.

```
 @Override
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
        if(getCurrentItem()==0){
            final int action = ev.getAction();
            switch(action & MotionEventCompat.ACTION_MASK){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                mStartDragX = ev.getX();
                if (x1<mStartDragX){
                    Log.i("TOUCH: ", "ACTION UP " + x1 + " : " + mStartDragX );
                    mListener.onSwipeOutAtStart();
                }else{
                    Log.i("TOUCH ELSE : ", "ACTION UP " + x1 + " : " + mStartDragX );
                    mStartDragX = 0;
                }
                break;
            }
        }else{
            mStartDragX=0;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I used @spacebiker answer but It is not work, setCurrentItem performed but not swipe, on MotionEvent.ACTION_UP it is not work but on MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE swipe but not correctly. On activity I use setCurrentItem with thread and worked.

```
public class ViewPagerFixed extends androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager {

    float mStartDragX;
    OnSwipeOutListener mOnSwipeOutListener;

    public ViewPagerFixed(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ViewPagerFixed(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void setOnSwipeOutListener(OnSwipeOutListener listener) {
        mOnSwipeOutListener = listener;
    }

    private void onSwipeOutAtStart() {
        if (mOnSwipeOutListener != null) {
            mOnSwipeOutListener.onSwipeOutAtStart();
        }
    }

    private void onSwipeOutAtEnd() {
        if (mOnSwipeOutListener != null) {
            mOnSwipeOutListener.onSwipeOutAtEnd();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if ((ev.getAction() & MotionEventCompat.ACTION_MASK) == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            mStartDragX = ev.getX();
        }
        try {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

        if (getCurrentItem() == 0 || getCurrentItem() == getAdapter().getCount() - 1) {
            float x = ev.getX();
            if ((ev.getAction() & MotionEventCompat.ACTION_MASK) == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if (getCurrentItem() == 0 && x > mStartDragX) {
                    onSwipeOutAtStart();
                }
                if (getCurrentItem() == getAdapter().getCount() - 1 && x < mStartDragX) {
                    onSwipeOutAtEnd();
                }
            }
        } else {
            mStartDragX = 0;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    public interface OnSwipeOutListener {
        void onSwipeOutAtStart();

        void onSwipeOutAtEnd();
    }
}
```

On Activity implements OnSwipeOutListener

```
public class ExapleActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ViewPagerFixed.OnSwipeOutListener{

    private ViewPagerFixed viewPager;
    private WormDotsIndicator dot;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.example_layout);
        
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        dot = findViewById(R.id.dot);

        ViewPagerAdapterUploadImage adapter = new ViewPagerAdapterUploadImage(this, this, viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        dot.setViewPager(viewPager);
        viewPager.setOnSwipeOutListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwipeOutAtStart() {
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

            this.runOnUiThread(() -> {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getAdapter().getCount() - 1, true);
            });

        }).start();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onSwipeOutAtEnd() {
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

            this.runOnUiThread(() -> {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
            });

        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Great ! Safe variant