# How to make an Android Step by Step Interactive Instruction

Tags: android

This might a vague question but this is i really want to know. We developing an android application and we want to put an interactive instruction on first use of the application. What do you call the interaction of the help/instruction most of the android application do have today? Can it be done using android studio? Thanks for the response.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement first launch tutorial like Android Lollipop apps: Like Sheets, Slides app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26954217/how-to-implement-first-launch-tutorial-like-android-lollipop-apps-like-sheets)

Comment: Hmm. Thank you sir, this gives me an idea to make our application more presentable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are refering to this library https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView. I've seen it used quite often.

And it can be used with AS, just add the dependency to your build.gradle  `compile com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.0.0'`

Comment: Thank you sir. This is what im looking for. Im new in android development and i wonder if this can be still implemented on kitkat version of device?

Comment: Yes, the min sdk version for the library is 9 (build.gradle), so that means it's supposed to work on Android 2.3 and above

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to add tutorial to your application
and as far as I know there is no built-in component for that
some applications use ViewPager for displaying tutorial
at first you have to decide what you want to present.