# Android - first launch interactive tutorial

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-viewpager

I'm writing a new app for android and I would like to implement also a first launch tutorial. In particular, the tutorial has to be interactive. Basically, after a user registers to the service, a minimum settings will be required.

I'd like something like today we have into Google Apps, like Sheets, Docs and so far. The exception there is that those tutorials have the aim to explain how the app works. Here I want to have something where user can input some data.

I was looking at [ShowcaseView](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView%20%22ShowCaseView) but seems to be deprecated and old in style.

So here the question is: what is the best way to implement that? ViewPager?

I also had a look to this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26954217/how-to-implement-first-launch-tutorial-like-android-lollipop-apps-like-sheets), but it did not help too much.

Any advice is really appreciated.

EDIT: I have found this other nice alternative. [AppIntro](https://github.com/PaoloRotolo/AppIntro) It seems what I was looking for. :)

Comment: Take a look at this other question on transparent demo screens: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12013334/4107809

Answer (score 5):

There are few I found by quick searching Github:

https://github.com/Seishin/showcaseview-android

https://github.com/worker8/TourGuide

https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView

I'm pretty sure you can find the right one for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in several ways that really depends on you and your app. Basically you can create a "Boarding" experience with ViewPager that will go thru the main screen of your app (with static images for example) where you explain the user what goes on in your app. The other way way is an interactive tutorial as the user already landed into your app - you can achieve this with something like Showcase (I'm pretty sure that there are libs on GitHub that are still maintained).

Comment: The tutorial should not be a simple "image showing", instead the user will have the change to set a profile photo and few personal details, like age - for instance.

If you could point me any libs, I'll really appreciate. I also searched on Android Arsenal, with no luck :-/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Roman Nuriks Wizard Pager code on Github as a starting point. It's not so much a library as a sample code showing you how to do what you want.

The general approach is to use a ViewPager with some form of navigation buttons to move the user forwards and backwards through the pager Fragments.

https://github.com/romannurik/Android-WizardPager