# Programmatically show Layout to preface an activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, layout-inflater

**What I want to do:**

I want to have multiple activities each prefaced with a page explaining to the user what the activity is about.

**What I'm currently doing:**

So my main class `BaseModuleActivity` extends `Activity` and I am trying to write a function called `showTutorial()` which will explain the next steps to the users.

Here is my attempt in doing so:

```
public void showTutorial(String title, String explanation){
               setContentView(R.layout.tutorial_screen);
        TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tutoTextTitle);
        tv1.setText(title);

        TextView tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tutoTextExplanation);
        tv2.setText(explanation);

        findViewById(R.id.tutoButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click
                //remove the tutorial's view
                findViewById(R.id.tutoLayout).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }
```

And this method is called in the following:

```
public class myFirstActivity extends BaseModuleActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);

        //First show tuto
        super.showTutorial(getString(R.string.upTitle),getString(R.string.upExplanation));

        //TODO then actually do the activity stuff
        /*
        (findViewById(R.id.next_button)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        */
    }
}
```

**Problem:**

I think the problem is mainly conceptual. I don't know the best approach to do this and the approach I'm taking is not working.

What I'm doing is not working because the view just become empty. I thought setting the visibility of the linearLayout to gone would make it disappear and the actual activity will able to take place.

**What I need:**

I need to understand if I can do what I want with my approach or not? Or what approach should I take.

I found some similar questions. However, the answer to these questions didn't seem to fit my problem.

I also looked into layout inflater and fragment, but layout inflater seem to be more for listView and fragment uses layout inflater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are some approaches to show a guide for your activity (or application).
First one, and probably the easiest, is to show a dialog/TextView when user enters an activity and explain the activity guide in that dialog/TextView using plain text. From your explanation, I think this one is what your are trying to do.
Second one is to use something like slides with pictures to explain about your activity (like [Google Sheets](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.docs.editors.sheets&hl=en) application).
Third one is to explain each control in your activity separatly by highlighting them (similar to how [Go Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gau.go.launcherex&hl=en) explains its feature on first launch)


You can find more info in below links:

[How to implement first launch tutorial like Android Lollipop apps: Like Sheets, Slides app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26954217/how-to-implement-first-launch-tutorial-like-android-lollipop-apps-like-sheets)
[Android - first launch interactive tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464917/android-first-launch-interactive-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that what you want is actually an introduction. Take a look at this project:

https://github.com/rubengees/introduction

From each introduction page you can launch the correspondent activity.