# How to create image slideshow in Android require some tutorial guides

Tags: android

How can i create image slideshow with string on android studio can you teach me with good example i'm a beginner of android with some knowledge[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DDlD.jpg).

Comment: ViewPager with tablayout is what you need

Comment: on ViewPager Michael Lam sir

Comment: if you have knoowledge, so you need to research before asking, [this is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33204139/8190366)

Answer (score 0):

All you have to look for Viewpager . 
[Viewpager](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)