# View pager onInterceptTouchEvent not generating event

Tags: android, touch-event, xml-layout

I have written an custom [ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13347008/2624806) but it's not generating event for Continuous Action.Move. On touch it generate DOWN once and MOVE event 2-3 time and that's it. Then after it not generate MOVE event.

Parent XML code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <example.animation.com.CustomPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:background="#123456"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />



</FrameLayout>
```

Added Child Fragment XML implementation:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fmParent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/txtIndex" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Any suggestion if I am missing anything here.

Comment: generating event?  what do you mean?

Comment: Finger move on ViewPager not generating any further event through onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev).

Comment: if you return true,  events got dispatched to onTouch

Comment: yes...here I require to intercept touch event. Since Child Fragment I mentioned here may be a list. So as far as I know using onInterceptTouchEvent I have to find whether event should pass to child or parent should handle this. 
Reference: http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html

Comment: sorry i don't understand what you really mean

Comment: So here I am using an ViewPager which contain Fragment as an child. Fragment has Expandable list view. But this List view displayed in half of the part of screen. Now I need to scroll Up (beyond upper half part) this list view on detection if two finger get placed. If single finger using to scroll then allow in bottom half part of screen...any suggestion?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71311/discussion-between-shubh-and-pskink).

Answer (score 0):

Probably some view catch the event, so if just the ViewPager should catch the touches you can change the return of the ViewPagerfrom:

```
return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
```

to:

```
return true;
```