# add new fragment on pageview swipe

Tags: android, android-fragments, adapter, viewpage

I want to add a new fragment everytime I swype right on the last fragment or left on the first one, dynamically. This fragment will be add to my adapater that will be set to my viewPager. Right now I have a static number of fragments defined in the setupViewPager and they "load" in the OnCreate method. Here is my code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.support.android.designlibdemo.Diafragment;
import com.support.android.designlibdemo.R;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        if (viewPager != null) {
            setupViewPager(viewPager);
        }

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String nome = intent.getStringExtra("nome");

        View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        TextView navUsername = headerView.findViewById(R.id.tv_drawerUsername);
        navUsername.setText(nome);

        TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE");
        Date date = new Date();
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        date = calendar.getTime();

        String day = sdf.format(date);

        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new Diafragment(), day);

        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        date = calendar.getTime();
        String dayplusone = sdf.format(date);
        adapter.addFragment(new Diafragment(), dayplusone);

        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        date = calendar.getTime();
        String dayplustwo = sdf.format(date);
        adapter.addFragment(new Diafragment(), dayplustwo);

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    static class Adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitles = new ArrayList<>();

        public Adapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragments.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitles.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragments.size();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitles.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just extend ViewPager and override onInterceptTouchEvent() like shown in here https://stackoverflow.com/a/13347008/2000083

Comment: I implemented it and Im using CustomViewPager myViewPager;. My doubt is, what sould I pass as a parameter when I use the  myViewPager.setOnSwipeOutListener(???);