# Detect swiping out of bounds in Android's ViewPager2

Tags: android, androidx, android-viewpager2

I'm using [ViewPager2](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2) and want to detect when the user swipes either to the left on the first page or the right on the last page.

I know this can be implemented using the old `ViewPager` like discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13346824/viewpager-detect-when-user-is-trying-to-swipe-out-of-bounds), but this approach is not feasible since `ViewPager2` is final and can't be subclassed.

`ViewPager2` provides the [OnPageChangeCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback) but this can't be used either since there are no page events when swiping out of bounds.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out a (slighly hacky) solution while I was typing this question.

It is based on the observation that the state `SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING` is only reached when the viewpager really settles on a new page. If there is only fruitless dragging on the first or last page then only the states `SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING` and finally `SCROLL_STATE_IDLE` are passed.

```
viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {

        private boolean settled = false;

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            super.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
            if (state == SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
                settled = false;
            }
            if (state == SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING) {
                settled = true;
            }
            if (state == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE && !settled) {
                doYourOutOfBoundsStuff();
            }
        }
    });
```

I'm not entirely happy, but this is the best I came across so far.

Answer (score 0):

thanks, @flauschtrud To handle better swapping right on the last index or swapping left to the first index of your child tab layout, I use this code for a challenge when I wanted to  change paging on nested tab layouts because SwipeChangeListener could not detect swap to the left & right when you were on the first index or the last index of the tab layout item

```
yourChildViewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object :
            OnPageChangeCallback() {
            private var settled = false
            override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {
                super.onPageScrollStateChanged(state)
                if (state == SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
                    settled = false
                }
                if (state == SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING) {
                    settled = true
                }
                if (state == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE && !settled) {
                    if (yourChildViewPager.currentItem == 0) {
                        backDirectionToParentViewPager()
                    } else {
                        forwardDirectionToParentViewPager()
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

Note: You can handle disable or enable paging in your parent view pager (ViewPager2) with this code:

```
   yourParentViewPager.isUserInputEnabled = (true or false)
```